# Why are the problems with the properties of the elements

Tags: javascript

I found this code in javascript book . why is the properties of the elementsnot defined and what is the cause for it and what is the solutoon . can someone give some sugestion on some core concepts this situations .

```
<form id="testForm" action="/">
<input type="text" id="id"/>
<input type="text" name="action"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
var form = document.getElementById('testForm');
assert(form.id === 'testForm',
     "the id property is untouched");
assert(form.action === '/', "the action property is untouched");
assert(form.getAttribute('id') === 'testForm',"the id attribute untouched");
assert(form.getAttribute('action') === '/',"the action attribute is untouched");
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what the question is. Do you mean that when you run this code, the assertions fail? Or are you confused about what "untouched" means?

Comment: When i run the code the first two assertion fail while the last two assertion dosent . What is the cause ? Thank you

Comment: Does the book not explain why the code behaves that way?

Answer (score 0):

If you've copied this code into a plain HTML file, and tried to run it, it will probably throw an error. The reason is that `assert` is not defined within this code snippet. Web browser javascript environments do not define `assert`.

The book you pulled this code from obviously uses a JS testing library that provides an `assert` function. The signature of that function appears to be `assert( condition , message_if_true )`.